# Get the selected radio button value outside oncheckedchanged in android?

Tags: android

I am working on android. In my page I have radio buttons and I need to get the selected radio button value. My issue is I am able to get the selected radio button 
value only in that onCheckedChanged method. But when I am trying to print the value outside the onCheckedChanged method it is not printing.
How can I get the value outside that method? Please help me out with this. I need the value outside also.

```
  My code:

        radiogroup = (RadioGroup) new RadioGroup(Page.this);

                layout.addView(radiogroup);

                for (int p = 0; p < arr.length; p++) {
                    RadioButton newRadioButton = new RadioButton(Page.this);

                    newRadioButton.setText(stringList6.get(p));
                    newRadioButton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

                    radbtn = Integer.parseInt(stringList5.get(p));
                    newRadioButton.setId(radbtn);

                    radiogroup.addView(newRadioButton);

                }


        radiogroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup,
                                    int checkedId) {

                    for (int h = 0; h < radioGroup.getChildCount(); h++) {
                      RadioButton btn = (RadioButton) radioGroup.getChildAt(h);

                        if (btn.getId() == checkedId) {

                          selectedop1 = btn.getId();
                            System.out.println("selected radio button inside"+ selectedop1);

                            return;
                                    }

                                }

                            }

                        });

System.out.println("selected radio button outside"+ selectedop1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a check in your function to see whether it is checked or not. If Yes then you can get its value.